# Compile error associated with std::unique_ptr and abstract classes

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have class that inherits from a base class. The base class contains pure virtual functions that are overridden in the derived class. I instantiate the base class object with std::unique_ptr of the derived class but get a compile time error

```
class Base { 
public:
    ~Base () = default;
    initBase () { count = 0; }

    virtual void method1() = 0; 
    virtual void method2() = 0;  

private:
    int count;
}; 

class Child final : public Base { 
public: 
    Child() = default;
    ~Child() = default;

    void method1() override { std::cout << "B Running method 1\n"; } 
    void method2() override { std::cout << "B Running method 2\n"; }
}; 

class myClass {
public:
    myClass(std::unique_ptr<Base> base) { _base(std::move(base)) };
    ~myClass() = default();

private:
    std::unique_ptr<Base> _base;
};

int main() {     
myClass obj = myClass(std::make_unique<Child>()); 
}
```

Compiler gives the following error:

```
error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type 'Base'
     { return unique_ptr<_Tp>(new _Tp(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...)); }
because the following virtual functions are pure within 'Base':
 class A {
'virtual void Base::method1()'
     virtual void method1() = 0;
'virtual void Base::method2()'
     virtual void method2() = 0;
```

Comment: Please show real code that anyone can cut/paste ***exactly as shown*** and reproduce your real compilation error, instead of something that's full of unrelated typos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several typos in your code:

In `Base`:

- Change

  `initBase () { count = 0; }`

  to

  `Base () { count = 0; }`

In `Child`:

- change

  `myClass(std::unique_ptr<Base> base) { _base(std::move(base)) };`

  to

  `myClass(std::unique_ptr<Base> base) : _base(std::move(base)) { }`
- change

  `~myClass() = default();`

  to

  `~myClass() = default;`

In `main()`:

- change

  `myClass obj = myClass(std::make_unique<Child>());`

  to

  `myClass obj(std::make_unique<Child>());`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Base { 
public:
    ~Base () = default;
    Base () { count = 0; }

    virtual void method1() = 0; 
    virtual void method2() = 0;  

private:
    int count;
}; 

class Child final : public Base { 
public: 
    Child() = default;
    ~Child() = default;

    void method1() override { std::cout << "B Running method 1\n"; } 
    void method2() override { std::cout << "B Running method 2\n"; }
}; 

class myClass {
public:
    myClass(std::unique_ptr<Base> base) : _base(std::move(base)) { }
    ~myClass() = default;

private:
    std::unique_ptr<Base> _base;
};

int main() {     
    myClass obj(std::make_unique<Child>()); 
    std::cout << "OK";
}
```

With those fixes in place, the code compiles fine.

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/8nmLYs)